# Country Italy unreachable

Tags: configuration

If in the file `torrc` is written

```
ExitNodes {at}
StrictNodes 1
```

Tor starts with an IP in Austria.

But if in the file `torrc` is written

```
ExitNodes {it} StrictNodes 1
```

Tor don't start with an IP in Italy, it starts in France.
Italy is in the Tor Circuit at the penultimate position.

Is this a Bug? What can I do?

My OS is Windows 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

GeoIP is often wrong, outdated or simply falisifed (maliciously or for fun).

GeoIP is harvested from whois information by MaxMind. This whois information is supplied by whoever owns the IP range, as such the IP range owner could claim to be in North Korea in their whois data and MaxMind would believe them.

There is no real link between an IP address and a geographic location, it's possible that both you and the site reporting the location of your IP have different versions of the GeoIP database.

For example I ran a relay that was falsely report to be on the wrong side of the globe for 6+ months because the IP addresses had recently changed hands.

Further more if MaxMind can't get an accurate enough "location" for the IP it simply makes it up, the results of believing in GeoIP are serious and MaxMind are [currently being sued over it](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/aug/09/maxmind-mapping-lawsuit-kansas-farm-ip-address). It's a concept we should all seek to dispell. I've written about it more [here](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/misconception.md#geoip-is-bullshit).

Comment: It's not a question of a false GeoIP.

Comment: I think it's not a question of a false GeoIP.

For example, if I open www.rait.it and want to watch live TV (ora in diretta), I  receive an geo-blocking-error with the comment "The streaming of this content is available in Italy only."

Comment: Some sites, especially national TV streams, will block known proxies, Tor and VPNs.